# .click() when there is no proper identifier

Tags: jquery, greasemonkey

Recently I started using Greasemonkey and I am not very familiar with JS or jQuery sintax but i can manage around with logic that any programmer have. :-)

I want Greasemonkey script to click one button. It sounds easy but I can't make it work althoug I tried many variations. It is hard to me to understand how can I uniquely identify this button because it has just type (button) and value (Insert Signature). I tried to identify it as "first child" of button type and with VALUE attribute but it is not working.
Do you have any advice for me people, because it is making me crazy.

```
<button type="button" onclick="genericAjaxGet('','c=tickets&amp;a=getComposeSignature&amp;group_id='+selectValue(this.form.to),function(o){insertAtCursor(document.getElementById('content'),o.responseText);});"><img src="abuse_files/document_edit.gif" align="top"> Insert Signature</button>
```

Currently this is the code I am using that do not work:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        requester
// @namespace   statistike
// @require     http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js
// @include     http://cerberus.eunet.rs:81/index.php/tickets/create
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

$('input[type="button"]:nth-child(1)') .trigger('click');
```

Comment: Is the button inside of another tag like a div or a span?

Comment: Is "Insert Signature" unique button text?

Comment: Do you need to wrap it in a document ready? `$(function(){ $('input[type="button"]:nth-child(1)') .trigger('click'); });` Are you sure jQuery is running? Is there any error in the console?

Comment: @ Zak: it is into div, form, table, then tr and td tags.
@Brad: it is unique.

Comment: @Bill: there is command before that clicker that works: $('input[name=reqs]') .val('my text');

Comment: Duh. You probably want `button[type=button]`. Not sure how I didn't see that earlier.

Comment: Bill you are right! :)
It was stupid of me to oversee that.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the "Insert Signature" text is unique, you can use the jQuery `:contains` selector:

```
$('button:contains("Insert Signature")')
```

http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/